# Going back after changing stateParams of $ionicHistory.backView()

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an android app using Ionic Framework.

In that, I have three views, `view1, view2 and view3`.

Navigation will be like `view1 -> view2 -> view3`

When moving back to `view2` from `view3`, I need to change a stateParam `param1` value of `view2` to perform some operations. Below code shows you that I am changing the stateParam value of `view2` when clicking back button in `view3`

Following is the code to override the action of android device backbutton

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function() {

      if ($state.current.name == "view3") {
          $ionicHistory.backView().stateParams = {param1:true};
          $ionicHistory.goBack(); // moves to view2
      } else {
          $ionicHistory.goBack();
      }

}, 100);
```

After moving back to `view2`, If I click back button now, it is moving to `view3` and not to `view1`.  Now I am able to view only `view3` and `view2` by clicking back button, Not at all moving to `view1`.

How to make back button to move to `view1` from `view2` Even after changing the stateParam value of `view2`?

Comment: Try $state.go('view2',{param1:true});

Comment: Emre, I tried it. But no luck. same results.

Comment: It will be kind of hardcoded but can you create a switch-case and write code for every case

Answer (score 2):

I've finally found a solution to that issue, unfortuately, it's a hack so it's a little bit ugly.

The tip is to not only update stateParams, but also stateId.

Please see bellow a re-usable answer :

```
var params = {param1:true};
var backView = $ionicHistory.backView();

var stateId = backView.stateName;
for (var key in params) {
    if (params[key] && params[key] !== "") {
        stateId += "_" + key + "=" + params[key];
    }
}

backView.stateParams = params;
backView.stateId = stateId;
$ionicHistory.goBack();
```

In your specific case, it could just be:

```
if ($state.current.name == "view3") {
    var backView = $ionicHistory.backView();
    backView.stateParams = {param1:true};
    backView.stateId = backView.stateName + "_param1=true";
    $ionicHistory.goBack(); // moves to view2
} else {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue,but my view2 is root,so I disabled the back when view3 back to view2,thus made back view3 disappear

```
   $ionicHistory.backView().stateParams = resultObject;
   $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({   disableBack: true });//this can
   $ionicHistory.goBack();
```

with this my code runs well,and for your destination,you can add a backview in view2.onenter() manually